# has_one with two foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, belongs-to, has-one

I have two classes Message and User. Message has sender_id and recipient_id both foreign keys for User. How to build relationship where I'll be able to get user for both sender and recipient, like @message.sender.name and @message.recipient.name

I tried to do it by this way:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base  

  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'sender'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'recipient'

end   

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :recivied_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'recipient'
  has_many :send_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'sender'
end
```

But it didn't help, when I'm trying to access to, for instance, @message.recipient.name it says that "undefined method `name'"

Comment: I think your solution is right. Are you sure your above example message has the field `recipient_id` set? Because you should get a `RecordNotFound` exception when it is set and the corresponding `User` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:class_name` property to set which class gets used for a foreign key:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :sender, :class_name => User
  has_one :recipient, :class_name => User
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sent_messages, :class_name => Message
  belongs_to :received_messages, :class_name => Message
end
```

Also, you say you are using `sender_id` and `recipient_id` for the foreign keys, but in your code you have `:foreign_key => 'sender'` and `:foreign_key => 'recipient'`.  Have you tried changing them to `:foreign_key => 'sender_id'` and `:foreign_key => 'recipient_id'`? So:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :sender, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  has_one :recipient, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sent_messages, :class_name => Message, # ...etc
  belongs_to :received_messages, :class_name => Message, # ...etc
end
```

Comment: what do you mean by didn't work?  did you get an error message? wrong data?  this is a two-way street :p

Comment: I updated topic with the example of code, because it's no possible to post it in comment :)

Comment: yeah, I've noticed this mistake also and fixed it, but didn't help either :(

Comment: it would help if you could find out more about what you are getting...do you know how to use `irb` with rails models? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#console

Comment: Ha, that helped, thank you. It was stupid mistake, just used the wrong class. Your method works