# has_one with more than one possible foreign key column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Family` class that includes a `mother_id` and a `father_id`.  From the Family model's perspective, it's important to know which parent is the mother and which is the father, but the mother and father as `Residents` have all the same attributes (i.e. database columns).  So ideally, I'd like my model files to look like this:

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :family, :dependent => :nullify, :foreign_key => :father_id
  has_one :family, :dependent => :nullify, :foreign_key => :mother_id
  attr_accessible :email, :cell, :first_name, :last_name
end

class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :father, :class_name => 'Resident', :foreign_key => 'father_id'
  belongs_to :mother, :class_name => 'Resident', :foreign_key => 'mother_id'
  attr_accessible :address, :city, :state, :number_of_children
end
```

This doesn't work.  `my_family.mother` and `my_family.father` work, so Rails seems to be happy with the double `belongs_to`.  However, `my_dad.family == nil`, indicating that the second `has_one` is overriding the first.  This is reasonable, because otherwise, what would happen if a resident_id showed up in both the mother_id and father_id columns?  (While I plan to add model-level validation to ensure that never happens, `has_one` doesn't talk to validation methods.)  Furthermore, what would `my_dad.family = Family.new` mean?  How would ActiveRecord choose whether to insert `my_dad.id` into `Family.mother_id` or `Family.father_id`?

From [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393561/has-one-with-two-foreign-keys), I got the idea to use different names, i.e. change the `has_one` lines to:

```
has_one :wife_and_kids, :class_name => 'Family', :dependent => :nullify, :foreign_key => :father_id
has_one :husband_and_kids, :class_name => 'Family', :dependent => :nullify, :foreign_key => :mother_id
```

My questions are:

1) Is there a better way to do it?  A different DB schema, perhaps?

2) Is database-level validation possible to supplement the model-level validation to ensure that `my_dad.id` can't show up in both the `mother_id` and `father_id` columns?

3) Can you think of better names than `husband_and_kids` / `wife_and_kids`? (Admittedly not a programming question...)

**EDIT:**
It occurred to me to add a family getter:

```
def family
  @family ||= self.wife_and_kids || self.husband_and_kids
end
after_save :reset_family
def reset_family
  @family = nil
end
```

This makes it syntactically cleaner (since I really wasn't a fan of `[husband|wife]_and_kids`), without creating any ambiguity since there's no setter.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you're facing is that you have a "conditional" foreign key, meaning the foreign key used to resolve the :family of a resident depends on whether the resident is a male or female (mother or father). The best way to deal with this in my opinion is to use STI (Single-Table Inheritance) to differentiate between the two cases.

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :cell, :first_name, :last_name
end

class Mother < Resident
    has_one :family, :dependent => :nullify, :foreign_key => :mother_id
end

class Father < Resident
    has_one :family, :dependent => :nullify, :foreign_key => :father_id
end
```

You can still use the Resident table, but you'll need to migrate a :type field of type string and store the value "Mother" or "Father" depending on the case. Also, place each of these class definitions in its own file in models/.

Edit: I think this also resolves the issues suggested in your second and third questions.

Edit2:

Given the current schema, you would need to create a [check constraint](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) on your `families` table. For one, active record doesn't have direct support for this, so you would have to execute raw sql to add the constraint. In theory, each time a value is added or changed in the "mother_id" column of "families", the check would have to cross reference with the "residents" table, ascertaining that the "type" column of the "resident" is "Mother." The SQL that would (theoretically) add this constraint is

```
ALTER TABLE families
ADD CONSTRAINT must_be_mother CHECK ((SELECT type FROM residents WHERE residents.id = families.mother_id) = 'Mother')
```

The problem is that this `CHECK` contains a subquery, and as far as I know, subqueries in checks are disallowed by many databases. (See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195881/what-sql-databases-support-subqueries-in-check-constraints) for specifics).

If you really want to implement a database-level validation here, you will likely need to change the schema by separating "residents" into "mothers" and "fathers."

Comment: I don't see why it answers my second question.  If a Resident has type 'male', but I try to insert its id into Family.mother_id, the database won't know it's invalid.

Comment: I suppose it indirectly answers the second question because it makes explicit validations unnecessary. When creating a new record, if you limit yourself to instantiating only Mother objects or Father objects, there is no ambiguity in what the foreign key will be. A Mother object has a foreign key :mother_id in the family table, and there is no way this can be confused with the :father_id

Comment: But that validation is in the model, i.e. in the app.  Question #2 is about database-level validation--i.e. what if in the future another app needs to connect to the database--how can I enforce that the future app's developers won't be able to make the mistake of putting a father in the mother_id column?
When you raun `rails generate model family mother_id:integer:uniq`, rails puts in the schema file:
`add_index "family", ["mother_id"], :name => "index_families_on_mother_id", :unique => true`
I want similar validation that says that no mother_id column can be entered in the father_id column

Comment: Looks reasonable.  I'm in middle of something else right now but when I have a chance to verify Edit #2 works for me, I'll mark your answer correct (assuming it is)

Comment: If you're talking about the SQL query I have there, it probably won't work. I tried it in postgres with no luck. The SQL specification doesn't seem to say anything about using subqueries in checks, and only a few databases (firebird for one) actually allow for it. My conclusion is that you'd have to separate mother and father if you want db-level validations.